# Pyqt 5.4.1 - how to use QOpenGLWindow?

Tags: python, opengl, pyqt

The following simple code outputs just `None` twice, what could be the reason for that? I can see black window, but cannot draw anything since have no access to GL functions.

```
from PyQt5.QtGui import QOpenGLWindow
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
import sys


class MainWindow(QOpenGLWindow):
    def paintGL(self):
        print self.context().versionFunctions()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a very nice example here: https://github.com/pbouda/stuff/blob/master/opengl/pyqt/chocolux.py

The issue was in incorrect GL profile: despite the fact that my video card has 4.4, PyQt supports only 2.0 and 2.1. That is sad to be honest...

```
1.0 failed: No module named _QOpenGLFunctions_1_0
1.1 failed: No module named _QOpenGLFunctions_1_1
1.2 failed: No module named _QOpenGLFunctions_1_2
1.3 failed: No module named _QOpenGLFunctions_1_3
1.4 failed: No module named _QOpenGLFunctions_1_4
1.5 failed: No module named _QOpenGLFunctions_1_5
2.0 is ok
2.1 is ok
3.0 failed: No module named _QOpenGLFunctions_3_0
3.1 failed: No module named _QOpenGLFunctions_3_1
```

I got this with the following code:

```
def paintGL(self):
        for i in xrange(0, 5):
            for j in xrange(0, 1000):
                version = QtGui.QOpenGLVersionProfile()
                version.setVersion(i, j)
                try:
                    if self.context().versionFunctions(version) is not None: print '{}.{} is ok'.format(i, j)
                except Exception as e:
                    print '{}.{} failed: {}'.format(i, j, e)
```

Comment: After all, I switched from PyQt to PySide and raw PyOpenGL which provides profiles up to 4.4